# Facebook Authentication Dialog not showing after clicking on Facebook Login Button in Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am working on login with facebook in Android. I am referring to the tutorial mentioned in the [Facebook Developers Scrumptious Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/). But I am failing at the first step itself i.e. Authentication. I am not able to login. I put a Log in button which is provided by the Facebook SDK (com.facebook.widget.LoginButton). After clicking on the Login button, it is not opening a web dialog that asks for the username and password. It just shows a progress dialog and disappears.
Following is the logcat for this problem:
04-17 10:43:22.629: D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(516): Webview loading URL: `http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=491106744284985&skip_api_login=1&cancel=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D491106744284985%26client_id%3D491106744284985%26redirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1&_rdr`

 What should be the problem? Is it because of the FB App which I created in the FB Developers? Am I missing something?